# RegEx split between two words two cut out text Python

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

test = '''starterword
    relevant info 1
    relevant info 3
    relevant info 2
endword

lots of irrelevant stuff
starterword
    relevant info 8
    relevant info 7
    relevant info 4
endword

lots of irrelevant stuff

starterword
    relevant info 420
    relevant info 90
    relevant info lol
endword
'''

pattern = re.split('/^starterword(.*?) \^endword/',test,flags=re.MULTILINE)#|re.DOTALL)
print(pattern )
print(len(pattern ))
```

I have a huge multiline string that i need some information from.
I want to cut out all the irrelevant stuff with RegEx but everything I tried didn't work. Most of the time there was irrelevant stuff in one list item that had relevant info.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `re.findall('^starterword\n(.*?)\nendword$',test, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The `(.*?)` portion of your regex doesn't work because the "relevant info" portion has newlines. I used `([\w\s]+?)` to get around that but was wondering if you knew a better way around that.

Comment: `.` with `re.DOTALL` matches any char including newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example text, this regex

```
^starterword\n([\w\s]+?)^endword
```

will return 3 groups

Group1

```
    relevant info 1
    relevant info 3
    relevant info 2
```

Group 2

```
    relevant info 8
    relevant info 7
    relevant info 4
```

Group 3

```
    relevant info 420
    relevant info 90
    relevant info lol
```

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YjS6VI/1).